# Name conflict between namespace and class template: different compiler behavior

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, c++14, language-lawyer

Different compilers [show different behavior](https://godbolt.org/g/4mY7jY) compiling the following code:

```
namespace N
{
    namespace Foo
    {
        template <typename>
        struct Foo
        {
        };
    }
}

template <typename Type>
using Foo = N::Foo::Foo<Type>;

namespace N
{
    template <typename Type>
    struct Bar : Foo<Type>
    {
    };
}


int main()
{
}
```

Compilers tested and their compilation flags:

- *clang++ 5.0.0*: `-std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors`
- *g++ 7.2*: `-std=c++14 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors`
- *vc++ 19.10.25017* (VS 2017): `/EHsc /Za /std:c++14 /permissive-`
- *icc 18.0.0*: `-std=c++14 -Wall -Werror`

Results of the compilation:

- *clang++*:

  > ```
  > 18 : <source>:18:15: error: expected class name
  >         struct Bar : Foo
  >                      ^
  > ```
- *g++*: successful compilation
- *vc++*:

  > ```
  > 18 : <source>(18): error C2516: 'Foo': is not a legal base class
  > 13 : <source>(13): note: see declaration of 'Foo'
  > 20 : <source>(20): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'N::Bar<Type>' being compiled
  > 18 : <source>(18): error C2143: syntax error: missing ',' before '<'
  > ```
- *icc*: successful compilation

Which compiler behavior is standard compliant?

Additional information:

- [same code with anonymous namespaces](https://godbolt.org/g/kz7RVW)
- [same code without templates](https://godbolt.org/g/qqgSRu)
- [same code without templates and with anonymous namespaces](https://godbolt.org/g/gCRwoF)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The spec says

> During the lookup for a base class name, non-type names are ignored ([basic.scope.hiding])

The name is `Foo<Type>`, it's a type name. And the name `N::Foo` is not a type name, so it must be ignored. In similar situations where certain names are ignored, the wording is more explicit though

> If a ​::​ scope resolution operator in a nested-name-specifier is not preceded by a decltype-specifier, lookup of the name preceding that ​::​ considers only namespaces, types, and templates whose specializations are types

Here, it doesn't only say *"type names"* or *"non-type names"* when it wants to allow `type-template<arguments>`. But it specifically says *"templates whose specializations are types"*. I think this confusion is the reason why there's implementation divergence here. The name `Foo<Type>` is what I would call a "composite name", because it consists of nested names inside of it. So it may be unclear *which* exact names in it are to be ignored and which not.

Comment: To be more precise: *clang++* and *vc++* have bugs in their implementation of the name resolution mechanism, *g++* and *icc* are standard-compliant in this area. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: And what about the same code without templates? Does *clang++* have a bug in this case, too?

Comment: @Constructor I don't know. The Standard is not quite clear here. I recommend to post a complaint to std-discussion. Without templates, clang clearly has a bug.

Answer (score 1):

The name `Foo` is looked up before the lookup of `Foo<Type>`. The lookup for `Foo` is not a lookup for a base class name, so the lookup rule in [class.derived]/2 does not apply.

Refer to [basic.lookup.unqual]/7:

> A name used in the definition of a class X outside of a member function body, default argument, noexcept-specifier, brace-or-equal-initializer of a non-static data member, or nested class definition25 shall be declared in one of the following ways:
>
> - before its use in class X or be a member of a base class of X ([class.member.lookup]), or
> - if X is a nested class of class Y, before the definition of X in Y, or shall be a member of a base class of Y (this lookup applies in turn to Y's enclosing classes, starting with the innermost enclosing class),26 or
> - if X is a local class or is a nested class of a local class, before the definition of class X in a block enclosing the definition of class X, or
> - if X is a member of namespace N, or is a nested class of a class that is a member of N, or is a local class or a nested class within a local class of a function that is a member of N, before the definition of class X in namespace N or in one of N's enclosing namespaces.
>
> [ Example:

```
namespace M {
  class B { };
}
namespace N {
  class Y : public M::B {
    class X {
      int a[i];
    };
  };
}

// The following scopes are searched for a declaration of i:

// 1) scope of class N​::​Y​::​X, before the use of i
// 2) scope of class N​::​Y, before the definition of N​::​Y​::​X
// 3) scope of N​::​Y's base class M​::​B
// 4) scope of namespace N, before the definition of N​::​Y
// 5) global scope, before the definition of N
```

> — end example ]

Namespace `N` is considered before the global namespace, so `N::foo` is found firstly, which causes the program ill-formed.